# Eloquent withtrashed() for soft deletes on eager loading query - Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use withTrashed() with eager loading. I've created a new _withtrashed function in my model, but the query comes back with a NULL for my client

Client model:

```php
// Client
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
}

// Client (withtrashed for soft deletes)
public function client_withtrashed()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client')->withTrashed();
}
```

Order controller:

```php
/**
 * Show order.
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $order = Order::with('client_withtrashed')    ---> it works normally with: Order::with('client') , except I don't get the soft deleted rows
            ->where('id', '=', $id)
            ->firstOrFail();
```

dd($order); displays an empty client

```
#relations: array:1 [
   "client_withtrashed" => null
```

Any ideas? I decided on the solution above because I couldn't get withTrashed() to work with my eager query  `$order = Order::with('client_withtrashed')->withTrashed()`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<s>Well you can't define that on a relationship</s>, but you can add constraints when you are eager loading:

```php
$order = Order::with(['client' => function ($query) {
        $query->withTrashed();
    }])
    ->where('id', '=', $id)
    ->firstOrFail();
```

You can check the eager loading constraints [in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading)

### EDIT:

**You can define withTrashed()** on your relationship, just make sure that your models are using the SoftDeleteTrait.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Client extends Eloquent {
    use SoftDeletingTrait;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that

Comment: Why cant you define the  `withTrashed` on a relationship? I've read other older posts on suggesting to add this in the model if it will be used throughout. Has this changed since Laravel 5.1?

Comment: You are right you can define the withTrashed on a relatioship, you just have to make sure that your models are using the SoftDeletingTrait; just edited my answer

Comment: Is this answer still relevant? It gives me `Call to undefined method Watson\Rememberable\Query\Builder::withTrash()`

Comment: Good answer, gives multiple solutions :) ...
bit late, but @martin you have a typo, it should be `withTrashed()` not `withTrash()`.

Answer (score -1):

In my case

```
\App\User::withTrashed()->findOrFail($userId)->first()
```

is giving me the wrong data (was giving the auth user data) then,

```
\App\User::withTrashed()->whereId($userId)->first()
```

gave me the exact data.

Else,
I believe you can do:

```
\App\User::withTrashed()->whereId($userId)->firstOrFail();
```

instead of `\App\User::withTrashed()->whereId($userId)->first()` only to make more secured.

Comment: The question was about eager loading data from a relationship.